# How to configure correctly Google App Engine Java Application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sdk, settings

I am following the [Google's Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating) on creating your first GAE Java Project. When I create it exactly the same as theirs I get lots of errors. I believe that it is caused wrong application configuration. Below are my configuration files:

***appengine-web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>my_app_id</application>
  <version>1</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

***appengine-web.xml***

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>guestbook</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>guestbook.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>guestbook</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/guestbook</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>guestbook.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for better readability, you might want to configure GAE/J using app.yaml 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

GAE will use the app.yaml to generate both web.xml and appengine-web.xml.  I also just find the app.yaml syntax much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is probably is to beat the evil zombie wizards by [enable Using Concurrent Requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests)

> By default, App Engine sends requests serially to a given web server.
>   You can configure App Engine to send multiple requests in parallel by
>   adding the  element to `appengine-web.xml`:

In your `appengine-web.xml`:

```
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
```